# OVS + Hostapd Raspberry pi setup

Tags: networking, wireless, access-point, bridge, hostapd

My experimental aim is to create OVS+Hostapd on raspberrypi 3B Module connected to PC as sdn controller.

initial ovs configuration is

```
ovs-vsctl add-br0 br0
```

`ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0`

Setting up pi as access point from the link:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

The only way is to bridge wlan0 and eth0 to share interconnection

`sudo apt-get install hostapd bridge-utils`

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
```

From the outlook br0 and eth0 enslaved on linux bridge and ovs bridge. am just wondering how i can play around to achieve my setup without conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I used three Rasberry Pi. One as OVS switch and the other two as Access point.
You need a USB to Ethernet adapters as well.
Now here are the steps to follow:

1. Install OVS on Rpi_1. (Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o54DUDkwI-M&list=PLQ7_U8wzAHAS2QbB-p_ihClopd-ds7dB7)
2. Make Rpi_2 and Rpi_3 as an Access point and bridge the internet from
   ethernet. (Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvOyafQeOoY&t=33s)
3. Connect other two Rpi_2 and Rpi_3 to via ethernet port of USB to Eth
   adapter.

   Provide internet access to OVS switch.

It's not exactly what you want but can help to achieve the same thing with access point traffic via SDN controller.
I have successfully controlled the traffic from the ports.

Comment: So this doesn't really answer the question, and just provides hints and links instead of an explanation?

Comment: To make the Raspberry Pi Access point, you required hostapd and dnsmasq Linux packages. To make Rasberry Pi as OVS you need to install OVS from source code and some Linux header installed. I was trying to avoid a long list of steps and it's an explanation to keep the answer as abstract as possible.

Comment: You might be able to create wireless OVS switch if you can manage conversion of wifi packets to ethernet frames. My best guess for now is too create virtual ethernet network interface and create a utility bridge between wireless interface and virtual ethernet interface and then configure OVS switch between eth0 ethernet interface and virtual ethernet interface.